# Upscale photos to at least 2x resolution (offline) for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

Upscaling images seems to be everywhere:

- [Upscaler Stockphotos](https://upscaler.stockphotos.com/) (free, online),
- [Gigapixel AI](https://www.topazlabs.com/gigapixel-ai) (paid),
- [Big JPG](https://bigjpg.com/) (online; unclear license for offline use)
- [Photopro AI](https://www.avclabs.com/purchase-photopro-ai.html) (paid, ~170 USD perpetual offline)
- [Photo Enhancer AI](https://www.dvdfab.cn/photo-enhancer-ai.htm) (paid, ~110 USD perpetual offline)
- [Hitpaw photo enhancer](https://online.hitpaw.com/online-photo-enhancer.html) (online)

But they all don't fit my needs, which are:

- works offline
- works on Windows (10/11)
- is gratis, also for commercial use, granted by a real license
- upscales images to 2x resolution in both dimensions (4x pixels)
- works at least on images smaller than 1024px (I don't need to upscale 10Mpx images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Upscayl [Github]](https://github.com/upscayl/upscayl), download from [Upscayl [Website]](https://www.upscayl.org/) has it:

- it's AGPL licensed, which allows commercial use
- upscales to 2x by default, but can do double upscale (4x) as well
- works on Windows 8 and above (tried myself on Windows 10)
- takes about 15 seconds to process a 1024px image (Ryzen 7 2700X)

Comment: Good find Thomas.  Also compatible with Linux and macOS!

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate: Thank you. On Stack Overflow it's best practise to remove tags from the title. You added tags. Is it different here?

Comment: You're welcome.  We don't have any hard-and-fast rules regarding that topic, but I find that it helps for SEO and to differentiate similar questions (e.g. if someone asks the same question for Android).  That's my thinking... does it seem reasonable to you?

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate: I also thought the title was a bit short. Also, there could be a lot of idential titles which only differ in tags. That's confusing.

Comment: Yes, your "Image inpainting" question had me scratching my head when I just saw the title! After I added a few more words to the title, I thought it made more sense.

Comment: BTW, I'm loving these new tools you are finding, and I also appreciate all the links you are providing to the tools that don't meet your requirements.  Some of them are new to me, and I think I will find them useful.

Comment: That's intended. Even if I don't get an answer, maybe someone has slightly different requirements and can use the online tools. So the question can be an answer at the same time :-)

Comment: It's very much appreciated.  Your questions often contain useful answers!